# Is there a way to block screenshots while using your app?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to block screenshots while using your app ?

Say you don't want users being able to snapshot profile pictures in your app.

Comment: Hardly. Whatever is on the screen, you won't be able to prevent the user to save the information they already have.

Comment: What do you mean by hardly, do you know of a solution ?

Comment: I mean no. The screen is always readable by the user and screenshot apps don't know about who is sending data to the screen, they are just saving the available pixel information.